# Where does node.js pull its installation path from?

Tags: windows-10, node.js

My Windows 10 desktop computer used to have a hard drive E: where I kept most of my programs, including my installation of Node.js. This drive recently died.

Due to the drive's frequent sporadic pre-death failures, I couldn't clone it, but at least was able to manually copy all my documents to C:, in a series of sessions.

This move didn't update things like environment variables and registry entries, of course, so I keep encountering links and redirects that don't work. One of them seems to be Node.js.

I am trying to reinstall Node.js on C:, from its current long-term-support version installer. However, when I start the installer, the only thing it does is issuing the warning "Invalid Drive: E:", followed by "Node.js Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified.", and the only thing I can do is press "Finish" to exit the installer.

Running "node" or "npm" commands in a cmd window only yields "unknown command" errors, so NPM/Node clearly aren't available. But obviously, there is something left pointing to the previous installation of Node.js on E:.

I manually checked all system and user environment variables, removing everything that still points to E:, including all sub-entries in things like PATH.

I also checked the registry with regedit, removing the "Node.js" section I found there, although it didn't seem to contain any meaningful data.

(I restarted the system after these steps, to ensure that it pulls the latest state of these variables.)

Still, the installer insists to refer to drive E:. Where does it pull this information from? What else do I need to check?

Comment: _"I am trying to reinstall Node.js on C:..."_ Just to clarify, did you uninstall Node first?

Comment: What do you have in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Node.js`?

Comment: @squillman No, I couldn't uninstall first. The drive that Node was on is gone. Without it, Windows pretended that Node wasn't installed and didn't offer me any uninstallers.

Comment: @harrymc That was it! The sub-value "InstallPath" of this registry entry pointed to E:. I deleted this registry entry and restarted the installer, this time successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was found in the the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Node.js`.

The item `InstallPath` of this registry key pointed to the
non-existent `E:`.

Deleting this registry item allowed restarting the installer successfully.